# Angular $http not sending header in OPTIONS pre-flight

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, cors

I'm trying to connect to an API with the $http service that requires a certain header to be defined for `POST` requests:

```
app.run(['$http', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post.hello = 'world';
}]);
```

However, my Angular app sends an `OPTIONS` request before the `POST`, and it does not appear to be sending the custom-defined header.

Check out the network tab in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tcqIb2q9zIQb3nf2SzyT

And watch see that where the request is supposed to send a `hello` header with the value of `world`, it actually isn't:

[image]

I see the `hello` in the `access-control-request-header`, but shouldn't it be on its own line? And why doesn't it send the value `world`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add a header, because you are going across different domains, requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. In this request the header name is sent in the access-control-request-headers to check if it is a safe header to send.

If it is safe to send then the header will be sent with the POST.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: So shouldn't the header be present in the `OPTIONS` call?

Comment: No, it first sends the header name in the access-control-request-headers by the OPTIONS method to check if it is a safe header to send.

Comment: There's one particular case when a custom header is needed on an `OPTIONS` call. When running a header-based versioning in Azure, stripping away the `Api-Version` header results in 404 errors. The resource path without a version header is not enough to match the resource. I don't have a solution for this problem so far.

Comment: @nolexa This question was posted a long time ago. I think you should be able to modify https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers in the preflight request to add `Api-Version` so that it will be sent.